# UIImage+Resize Category extension Errors and Warnings iOS 7

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I am getting some concerning errors by using a Category extension for UIImage class in the UIImage+Resize Category extension found [here](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGImageUtilities/tree/master/Classes). I am using Xcode 5.1.1.

**Question**: Is there a better way of using other things in **Quartz2D** or some other framework to resolve these issues and future proof the Category Extension for UIImage?

Here is the console output:

- : **CGBitmapContextCreate**: **unsupported parameter
  combination**: 8 integer bits/component; 32 bits/pixel; 3-component
  color space; unrecognized; 1200 bytes/row.
- :    **CGContextConcatCTM**: invalid context 0x0. This is a
  serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an
  invalid context     and is thereby contributing to an overall
  degradation of system    stability and reliability. This notice is a
  courtesy: please fix this    problem. It will become a fatal error in
  an upcoming update.
- :    **CGContextSetInterpolationQuality**: invalid context
  0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses,
  is using an    invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an
  overall    degradation of system stability and reliability. This
  notice is a    courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a
  fatal error in an    upcoming update.
- **CGContextDrawImage**: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context
  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system
  stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this
  problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
- :    **CGBitmapContextCreateImage**: invalid context 0x0. This
  is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using
  an    invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall
  degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a
  courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an
  upcoming update.

I am grabbing the imageView image and calling the method:

```
if (image != nil) {
            //present our image in the image view
            _imageView.image = image;

            //make half size thumbnail.
            CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(300,300);

            image = [image resizedImage:imageSize interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationHigh];
}
```

Here is the Category Extension Private Helper Method that contains all the issues:

```
// Returns a copy of the image that has been transformed using the given affine transform and scaled to the new size
// The new image's orientation will be UIImageOrientationUp, regardless of the current image's orientation
// If the new size is not integral, it will be rounded up
- (UIImage *)resizedImage:(CGSize)newSize
                transform:(CGAffineTransform)transform
           drawTransposed:(BOOL)transpose
     interpolationQuality:(CGInterpolationQuality)quality {
    CGFloat scale = MAX(1.0f, self.scale);
    CGRect newRect = CGRectIntegral(CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width*scale, newSize.height*scale));
    CGRect transposedRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, newRect.size.height, newRect.size.width);
    CGImageRef imageRef = self.CGImage;

    // Fix for a colorspace / transparency issue that affects some types of
    // images. See here: http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/comment-page-2/#comment-39951

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(
                                                NULL,
                                                newRect.size.width,
                                                newRect.size.height,
                                                8, /* bits per channel */
                                                (newRect.size.width * 4), /* 4 channels per pixel * numPixels/row */
                                                colorSpace,
                                                kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault
                                                );
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    // Rotate and/or flip the image if required by its orientation
    CGContextConcatCTM(bitmap, transform);

    // Set the quality level to use when rescaling
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(bitmap, quality);

    // Draw into the context; this scales the image
    CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, transpose ? transposedRect : newRect, imageRef);

    // Get the resized image from the context and a UIImage
    CGImageRef newImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap);
    UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImageRef scale:self.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];

    // Clean up
    CGContextRelease(bitmap);
    CGImageRelease(newImageRef);

    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: I am getting same warnings in IOS8, moreover, in IOS8 the uiimage returned is nil, so I cannot see the resized images... Could you resolve it??

Comment: mmmm in my case. I found that the context cannot be created:   CGBitmapContextCreate: unsupported parameter combination: 8 integer bits/component; 32 bits/pixel; 3-component color space; kCGImageAlphaLast; 448 bytes/row.        :(

Comment: Hey @EvaMadrazo look at my answer below. I hope this helps you! Peace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the issue *resolved* after some fiddling with **CGBitmapContextCreate** for Quartz.

There are some "braniacs" out there who can explain why this works but as of iOS7 and now recently, iOS8 (Xcode 6.0), this code works for me. Below is the code piece I changed:

```
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(
                                                NULL,
                                                newRect.size.width,
                                                newRect.size.height,
                                                CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef), /* bits per channel */
                                                (newRect.size.width * 4), /* 4 channels per pixel * numPixels/row */
                                                colorSpace,
                                                CGImageGetBitmapInfo(imageRef)/*SOLVED: instead of a constant here add this CGImageGetBitmapInfo(imageRef)*/
                                                );
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
```

I had to change somethings like where it was hardcoded for (**size_t bitsPerComponent**) part I used **CGImageGetBitsPerComponent**(*imageRef*) because I wanted it to be the bits per component of whatever the *imageRef* was inputting not just 8 bits. The next bit (pun intended) was to solve the cranky "**kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault**" which was blowing chunks, but by this time I found that being dynamic was useful so I used **CGImageGetBitmapInfo**(*imageRef*) which returns a constant (Returns the bitmap information for a bitmap image) that specifies the type of bitmap data and whether the alpha channel is in the data.

I hope this helps someone, and I welcome anyone to help explain this better as I know there are better folks to do that here. Cheers!

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer.      This is strange, but your code is the original code that I was testing first, it gives me a null context and the commented errors.  This works for you in IOS8 Xcode6 ??.  The error I obtain is: <Error>: CGBitmapContextCreate: unsupported parameter combination: 8 integer bits/component; 32 bits/pixel; 3-component color space; kCGImageAlphaLast; 436 bytes/row.

Comment: In my case. Changing   CGImageGetBitmapInfo(imageRef)-> kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst     makes the magic (magic because I do not understand why! :))

Comment: me too, but I would love to find someone who can explain that to me lol @tony.stack